# error C2143:Syntax error: lack of ";" (in front of the ". ")

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I try to call `HuffmanTree1.CreateHfmTree(char Str,int m,int n);`in button function .when run it give me **error C2143: Syntax error: lack of ";" (in front of the ". ")**.

it's translation of  语法错误 : 缺少“;”(在“.”的前面)

my code is below:

```
void CHuffmanTreeDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{      // TODO: 在此添加控件通知处理程序代码
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    if (m_radio1=1)
    {
        char*pszFileName="C:\C++\HuffmanTree\HuffmanTree\WData.txt";
        CStdioFile myFile;
        CFileException fileException;
        if(myFile.Open(pszFileName,CFile::modeCreate|CFile::typeText|CFile::modeReadWrite),&fileException)
        {   AfxMessageBox("打开成功");
        myFile.SeekToBegin();
        CString str1;
        myFile.ReadString(str1);
        CString str2;
        AfxMessageBox(str1+str2);
        ifstream ifs("WData.txt");
        ofstream ofs("WCode.txt"); 
        char str[1000]; 
        char Str[100]; 
        int i=0,j,m[100],h,k=0; 
        int n=0; 
        char ch; 
        while(ifs.get(ch)) 
        { 
            if(ch!='\n') 
            {str[n++]=ch;}
            for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
            { 
                j=0;h=0; 
                while(str[i]!=str[j]) 
                    j++; 
                if(j==i) 
                { 
                    Str[k]=str[i]; 

                } 
                else 
                    continue; 
                for(j=i;j<n;j++) 
                { 
                    if(str[i]==str[j]) 
                        h++; 
                }      
                m[k]=h; 
                k++; 
            } 
            HuffmanTree1.CreateHfmTree(char Str,int m,int n); 
            cin.get();

            m_length=n;
            m_string1="报文的编码已经保存在WCode.txt";
            UpdateData(FALSE);
        }
        }
        else
        {
            TRACE("Can't open file%s,error=%u\n",pszFileName,fileException.m_cause);
        }
        myFile.Close();
    }   
}
```

thanks for your help :D

Comment: Is it me, or are you missing a main function? Or have an extra ending brace somewhere.

Comment: Your usage of \ inside of the string constant should be escaped or just use / instead. Although this is not the error.

Comment: How about highlighting the line the error is on?

Comment: This is probably a bug `if (m_radio1=1)` (`==` instead of `=`), but it isn't the syntax error.  The line `if(myFile.Open(pszFileName,CFile::modeCreate|CFile::typeText|CFile::modeReadWrite),&fileException)` is also odd, using a comma expression in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
HuffmanTree1.CreateHfmTree(char Str,int m,int n);
```

is odd.  It is more or less a function declaration, but lacks a return type.  It isn't a call to a function; you'd not list the types.  If you're trying to call a function, then drop the `char`, and the two `int`, and maybe rename the other arguments.  I don't see a class variable `HuffmanTree1` that the code can be using — that makes it a global variable, or one otherwise defined out of this function.  Are you sure that's good interface design?  Passing values to functions in parameters is generally better than using 'global' variables.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to call the function, or declare it? Either way, it isn't valid to have a period in the function name, unless you have a variable called HuffmanTree1 which references a class with this member function.